# Really don't understand how to find this angle

Tags: geometry

[image]

How to find this angle? 
Can't think of any way.

Answer (score 3):

Hint. By the [Law of sines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines) applied to the $\triangle DEF$,
$$\frac{|DE|}{\sin(\angle DFE)}=\frac{|DF|}{\sin(\angle DEF)}.$$
We have that $|DF|=R$ and $\angle DEF=2\alpha$. Find $|DE|$ and $\angle DFE$.

Can you take it from here? Now you have "a way". Show your effort!

Answer (score 1):

Some hints for the remaining calculations up to $\cos(2\alpha)$

- What is the nature of triangle DEA ? --> find DE
- It verifies  $2\cos(\alpha)\sin(2\alpha)=\cos(3\alpha)$
- Simplify by $\cos(\alpha)$ and the resulting expression only has trigonometric lines of $2\alpha$.
- This leads to solving $8x^2-4x-3=0$

Note that the figure helps discarding unwanted solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Wlog take radius of circle as unity. (in place of 2)

Take DF positive x-axis, DA as negative y-axis and next take projection of  $DE$ to $DA$ and again along the $(x,y)$ axes as coordinates of a circle with origin at D.

$$ DE = DA \cos \alpha, x_E=DE \sin \alpha;\, y_E=DE \cos  \alpha;\, $$

$$ (x_E,y_E) = - 2(\sin \alpha \cos \alpha ,\cos^2 \alpha) \tag1 $$

For point $F, x_F=1, y_F=0$ and slope of EF=

$$ \dfrac{2c^2}{1+2 s\,c }= \dfrac{1+\cos 2 \alpha}{1+ \sin 2 \alpha} $$

using Weierstrass trig half angle relations with $ t= \tan \alpha$

$$ \dfrac{1+(1-t^2)/(1+t^2)}{1+2t/(1+t^2)}=\dfrac{2}{(1+t)^2} \tag2 $$

This is the same as reciprocal of $ \tan 3\alpha\tag3 $

as it makes angle $3 \alpha $ external angle with $AD$ when cutting between $(D,A)$

$$ \dfrac{1-3 t^2}{3t-t^3} \tag4$$

Equate them, cross multiplying and simplifying you get a fourth order trigonometric polynomial having 4 solutions with two real roots.

$$ 3 t^4 +6 t^3 +2 t^2 +4 t -1  =0 \tag5 $$

*Results*

First solution

$$\alpha_1= 2.0341 = -63.82 ^{\circ},\quad \cos 2 \alpha_1= -0.6107$$

Second solution

$$ \alpha_2= 0.21181 =11.5989 ^{\circ}, \quad \cos 2\alpha_2 = 0.9141 $$

The one you sketched is nearer to $ \alpha \approx 12^{\circ}$ second case that I also verified with a construction. Hope you would sketch the second solution also.

EDIT1:

An error in coefficient of $t^3$ is noticed and corrected along with error regarding analytical solution..shown possible by farruhota.

$$ 3 t^4 + 4 t^3 +2 t^2 + 4 t -1  =0 \tag5 $$

Accordingly

$$\alpha_1= -57.1476 ^{\circ},\quad \cos 2 \alpha_1= -0.411438 $$

$$\alpha_2= 12.1476 ^{\circ}, \quad \cos 2\alpha_2 = 0.911438. $$

Answer (score 0):

Apply the law of sines to $\Delta AED$ and $\Delta DEF$:
$$\begin{cases}\frac{DE}{\sin \angle DAE}=2R\\ \frac{DF}{\sin 2\alpha}=\frac{DE}{\sin (90^\circ-3\alpha)}\end{cases} \Rightarrow \begin{cases}DE=2R\cos \alpha \\ \frac{R}{\sin 2\alpha}=\frac{2R\cos \alpha }{\cos 3\alpha}\end{cases} \Rightarrow \\
\cos 3\alpha=2\sin 2\alpha \cos \alpha \Rightarrow \\
\cos\alpha \cos 2\alpha-\sin \alpha \sin 2\alpha=2\sin 2\alpha \cos \alpha \Rightarrow \\
\cos 2\alpha-2\sin^2 \alpha=2\sin 2\alpha \Rightarrow \\
2\cos^2 \alpha-1-2\sin^2 \alpha=2\sin 2\alpha \Rightarrow \\
 2\cos 2\alpha-2\sin 2\alpha =1 \Rightarrow \\
\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\cos 2\alpha -\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\sin 2\alpha=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}\\
\cos (2\alpha +45^\circ)=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4} \Rightarrow \alpha \approx 12.15^\circ \Rightarrow \\
\cos 2\alpha \approx 0.669.$$